# Getting my location on android 4.2.2

Tags: java, android, android-layout, gps, location

I am a beginner in android development. I was trying a very simple code to get my location through the device gps and post it in a textView. I am not having any errors though when I start the application on the emulator it fails to start and I get this message "unfortunately test1 has stopped ".

**This is my manifest file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.test1"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.test1.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

`

**this is my activity_main code :**

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

**This is my main_activity.class code :**

```
package com.example.test1;

import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView textView;
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    LocationManager manager =
    (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Location loc = manager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            textView.setText("latitude: " + loc.getLatitude()
              + "\nlongitude: " + loc.getLongitude());

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

   }
```

Any help on making it work ??

Comment: Please provide your logcat report.

Comment: Have you tried running the app on a real device? Maybe the emulator has a problem with location access.